# Is there a difference between declaring a variable in the LOC, VAR, and VARIABLES scopes?

Tags: coldfusion, scope

I see all three notations used frequently, and I'm wondering what the differences are between them:

```
<cfset var foo = "bar" />
<cfset local.foo = "bar" />
<cfset variables.foo = "bar" />
<cfset arguments.foo = "bar" />
```

Comment: As Daniel's answer outlines, local is a valid scope in ColdFusion 9 and Railo. "loc" is not a valid scope. If you set a variable 'loc.foo = 'bar'; you are actually creating variables.loc.foo = 'bar'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**var** and **local** are the same scope and they are available only to the method/function in which they are declared. The local scope is new to CF 9 before that you used var to create variables that only existed in the method.

**Variables** is available to the entire cfc or cfm page in which they are declared and any included templates.

**arguments** is used for arguments passed into a method/function and only exists with in it.

Comment: @"var and local are the same scope" - only in CF9 (-compliant engines).  In CF8 or earlier, local would be a struct in the variables scope unless you do a "var local = structNew()" first.

Answer (score 3):

If you are wondering why use `local` over `var` in, for example, a CFC function, then consider these two examples:

```
<cffunction name="foo" returntype="query" output="false">

  <cfset var myQuery = "" />

  <cfquery name="myQuery">
    select * from bar
  </cfquery>

  <cfreturn myQuery />

</cffunction>
```

First you have to declare the variable as a `var` and then use it. Contrast with:

```
<cffunction name="foo" returntype="query" output="false">

  <cfquery name="local.myQuery">
    select * from bar
  </cfquery>

  <cfreturn local.myQuery />

</cffunction>
```

Essentially it cuts out all these `var` statements for loop variables and queries etc. One less line of code! :)

I hope that helps.

Comment: For older versions of ColdFusion, adding the line `<cfset var local = StructNew()>` recreates this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I think you mean `local` scope, not `loc` (I am not aware of a scope called `loc`)

```
<cfset var foo = "bar" />
<cfset local.foo = "bar" />
```

Are supposed to be exactly the same. The variable will be private within the function it is defined in.

The variables scope, within a CFC, will create a variable private within an instance of the CFC (as opposed to the function)

Outside a CFC, I think the variables scope will be private whithin the template it is creataed in.